# How to write this function and compute integrations?

Tags: python, function, math, numerical-integration

I want to define this function in Python:

```
F(s) = integration(f(x, a), 0, s)
```

where `f(x, a)` can be any function of x. Here `a` is a constant.

Example: `f(x,2)=exp(2*x/(2+x))`

and compute its integration in Python:

```
value = integration(F(rho)-F(s),0,rho)   # here rho is a given constant.
```

So far, I've calculated the integration of "f" (not the function above) by hand and then used from `scipy.integrate` import quad to compute the last integration. But, it is not possible to calculate the integrations of every function by hand. For example the above function "f".

Comment: you can generate many many x,f(x) points of this function and calculate the area of the slices and sum them up to approximate the definite integral

Comment: Isn't it just `dblquad` what you want? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad

Comment: what exactly is the problem? You do not know how to add function points with small dx step? or handling singularities? or computing function value for some `x` as it is stored as text (expression evaluation) ?

Comment: No, this is not a double integration. @ Alex Fish

Comment: The problem is how to find the value of this integration  "integration(F(rho)-F(s),0,rho)" . Sorry, I do not know any of your methods.

Comment: why don't you try the [rectangle method approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def integration(f,a,b):
    """
    compute the integrale of f on [a, b]
    :param f: function
    :param a: left point of the interval
    :param b: right point of the interval
    :return: the value of the integrale
    """
    # we can use for instance the rectangle methods, but any method would be ok (the trapezoid method also...)
    N = 1000  # number of point you want to sample
    h = 1/(N+1)  # the discretization step
    integral = 0
    for k in range(N + 1):
        point = a + h*k
        integral += h * f(point)

    return integral

import numpy as np
print("with integration method", integration(np.exp, 0, 1))
print("by hand", np.exp(1) - 1)
print("difference", abs(integration(np.exp, 0, 1) - (np.exp(1) - 1)))

print("\n")
print("Now let's try with this function exp(2*x/(2+x))")
print("with integration method", integration(lambda x: np.exp(2*x / (2 + x)), 0, 1))
```

Comment: dallonsi, Thank you for help. But, if you read my question again you will see that, the upper case function "F" is a function of a variable "s" which the upper limit of the integration of the lower case function "f".  After defining "F"  I want to find its integration from 0 to rho( a constant).

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. So basically what you want is :
integrale from 0 to \rho of (integral from 0 to s of f(x,a) dx) ds.
Easy peasy, I can update my code if you confirm that it's what you want.